# Blender 2.82 - Unknown lines showing up on object

Tags: modeling, edges

I am modeling in Blender 2.82 using the Mirror modifier.  Several lines on edges are showing up on the object and I can't get rid of them.  I can't select them nor the corresponding vertices.  The number of lines is increasing each time I make modifications onto the object in edit mode.

What are these and what did I do to cause them?

[image: The lines are along the chin, jaw, and neck.]

Comment: Can you check for duplicate / non-manifold geometry, and maybe post a picture in wireframe as well?

Comment: Found out it was the normals had to be recalculated.